# GCloud Functions: load error: File ./dist/index.js that is expected to define function doesn't exist

Tags: gcloud

When trying to deploy to google cloud functions I get the response

```
load error: File ./dist/index.js that is expected to define function doesn't exist
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

It didn't upload my `dist` folder, because that was gitignored. In `.gcloudignore` I could remove the addition of gitignore by deleting `#!include:.gitignore` from the file.